# showing $\sum_n a^n/n$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

showing $\sum_n a^n/n$ is convergent where $0 < a < 1$. I'm pretty stuck on this. I have tried letting $ a = 1/b$ where $b > 1$ and considering $\sum_n \frac{1}{b^nn}$ but to no avail. Any hints please

Comment: just a point but its convergent for a=0 as well.

Answer (score 2):

If $0<a<1$ then $\sum a^n$ converges, so the given series converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: check the Taylor series of $\log(1-x)$, with $\left|x\right|
 <1$.